# Django-CMS Unpublished page still navigable

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-cms

I have 3 sites with Django-CMS sharing the same database and code but in different folders (the SITE_ID conf changes from folder to folder). They were suppose to have translations in `en` but for now we just want to show the `pt` pages so I unpublished all `en` pages. In my first site it works ok but in the other the `en` pages are visible in the published site instead of redirecting to the correspondent `pt` page as it happens in the first site. I tried to add to settings:

```
CMS_PAGE_CACHE = False
```

But still got the same problem. Also I checked and all the sites have the last svn commit and they have the `pt` language as the default one.

Do you know what could be happening?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Is the `hide_untranslated` option set to `True` in the `CMS_LANGUAGES` collection in `settings.py`?